# Suddenly Cannot Debug Typescript: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for .... Unknown Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core, ionic-framework

I need to debug my `Ionic React` application on `Android Emulator`, but suddenly I cannot see the source file to debug it.

[image]

[image]

I cannot debug from `bundled js`, but the css files are fine tho.

It was not like this before, suddenly today it gives me this error, I cannot debug anything.

What can cause this errors? I cannot see the error message everywhere.

Please help.

---

### I HAVE TRIED

I even try to revert to my last git commit when the error was not exist, apparently when I try to debug my last version, this error comes. I suppose there is something wrong with the chrome browser or maybe the `Android Emulator`.

---

### UPDATE

I tried to remove my `Android Emulator` and re-created again, but the errors are still there.

I even tried to debug with `Microsoft Edge` in edge://inspect, there errors are still there.

I tried to open my other application coded in `Ionic React`, the application was deployed a long time ago without any of these errors, but now the errors are there.

I have no clue what is happening.

---

### USING MOBILE PHONE WORKS

I tried to debug it in my mobile phone. It works there is no error. So I suppose there is a problem on `Chrome` to `Android Emulator` communication.

Comment: Do you have `"config": {"ionic_source_map_type":"#inline-source-map"}` in your `package.json` file?

Comment: No I do not. Should I add it?

Comment: Yes, try adding it.

Comment: I have added it, nothing is changed. Same error.

Answer (score 2):

There really is a problem with my `Android Emulator`. I tried to create another emulator with different `API Level`. It works, I suppose removing the emulator from `AVD Manager` in `Android Studio` and re-create it, does not really reset the emulator.

My problematic emulator was in `API 30` after I create `API 29` and debug in it, it works fine.